# (Quicksight) Remove duplicate values from field

Tags: amazon-web-services, duplicates, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

How can I only keep unique values from a field?

I only need data from unique values of my field, but there isn't a function that does that in a calculated field (that I know of).

Comment: Could you speak to your end goal a little more? Also, could you describe what data sources you are using?

Comment: Specifically, what kind of visuals do you want to show with duplicates removed?

Comment: @mjgpy3 a bar graph showing the correct cost values for the now unique numbers.